# Link matching fails inside of foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach

### getlink.html

```
// all other basic html tags are here which is not need to understand this like(head,body etc)
<a href="website.html">This is the website NO # 1</a>
<a href="http://www.google.com/">This is google site</a>
```

### PHP

```
<?php
$file = file_get_contents('getlink.html');

$matches = preg_match_all('/<a(?:[^>]*)href=\"([^\"]*)\"(?:[^>]*)>(?:[^<]*)<\/a>/is'
                            ,$file,$match); // work fine
$test1 = preg_match_all('/href=\"((?:https?|ftp)\:\/\/\w+\.[\w-]+\..+)\"/i'
                            ,$file,$test); // work fine

foreach($match[1] as $links) {      

            if ($match[1] == $test[1]){ // write $match[1] not $links
                                        // bcs $links does not work
      echo 'True'.'<br />';
    } else {
     echo 'False'.'<br />';
    }       
                                }

?>
```

When I run it, it returns `false` both times, instead of one time `false` and the second time `true`.

Second link should match with `$test[1]`. If I remove the first link, it return `true`,

Please help me, I'm really worried.

Comment: You're not doing anything with `$links`...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please refer to the [FAQ] and [Editing FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) on how to ask and format question properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($match[1] as $links) {      

if ($match[1] == $test[1])
```

You're calling it $links but not referring to to that within your loop.

Answer (score 0):

I can only guess with what little information you have given, but I'm assuming you're looking for any links which are in both `$matches` and `$test1`? If so, this should be what you need:

```
foreach($match[1] as $links)
{      

  if (in_array($links, $test[1]))
  {
    echo 'True<br />';
  }

  else
  {
    echo 'False<br />';
  }       

}
```

If this is indeed the case, perhaps you'd prefer to use this which requires less code:

```
echo count($match[1]) == count(array_diff($match[1], $test1)) ? 'False' : 'True';
```

Answer (score 0):

A. You are don't doing anything would `$link`

B. If you run

```
var_dump($match[1]);
var_dump($test[1]);
```

Output

```
array
  0 => string 'website.html' (length=12)
  1 => string 'http://www.google.com/' (length=22)
array
  0 => string 'http://www.google.com/' (length=22)
```

Can you see that `$test [1]` does not exist

C. What you should do is use `in_array` but multiple True would be printed ..

```
foreach ( $match [1] as $links ) {
    if (in_array ( $links, $test [1] )) {
        echo 'True' . '<br />';
    } else {
        echo 'False' . '<br />';
    }
}
```

To get either true or false use `array_intersect`

```
$result = array_intersect ( $match [1], $test [1] );
if (count ( $result ) > 0) {
    echo 'True' . '<br />';
} else {
    echo 'False' . '<br />';
}
```